# JavaFX prevent opening new stage (window) on buttonclick

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code which opens up a new JavaFX stage (let's call it window).

```java
openAlertBox.setOnAction(e -> {
        AlertBox alert = AlertBox.getInstance();
        alert.display("AlertBox","Cool");
});
```

Now I want to prevent user from opening a new window on every click (So if user already opened a window then on another click, nothing should happen because window is already opened)

This is my display method:

```java
public void display(String title, String message) {
    Stage window = new Stage();

    window.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setMinWidth(250);

    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText(message);

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //Display window and wait for it to be closed before returning
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't you want to make it modal, so you block events to other windows?

Comment: No. I specifically need to be non blocking modal. Because for user experience purposes I want to make it so that you dont have to close it every time

Comment: OK, I was just reading the comments in your code.

Comment: I edited my code. Removed this confusing comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single window and reuse it, instead of creating a new one each time. Then you can either just check if it is showing:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowAndWaitNonModalTest extends Application {

    private Stage alertWindow ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button show = new Button("Show");

        alertWindow = new Stage();

        show.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (! alertWindow.isShowing()) {
                Button ok = new Button("OK");
                Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(ok), 250, 250);
                alertWindow.setScene(scene);
                ok.setOnAction(evt -> alertWindow.hide());
                alertWindow.showAndWait();
            }
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(show), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

or you can disable whichever control shows it when it is showing:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowAndWaitNonModalTest extends Application {

    private Stage alertWindow ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button show = new Button("Show");

        alertWindow = new Stage();

        show.setOnAction(e -> {
            Button ok = new Button("OK");
            Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(ok), 250, 250);
            alertWindow.setScene(scene);
            ok.setOnAction(evt -> alertWindow.hide());
            alertWindow.showAndWait();
        });

        show.disableProperty().bind(alertWindow.showingProperty());

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(show), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```